# Cloning a git repo to /home/public and not /home/public/exampleproject?

Tags: git, ssh, console, clone, host

I have clone a github repo onto my web server using ssh, but when I did it created a sub folder instead of pulling the files to the 'root' folder. For example, when using:

```
cd /home/public
git pull GITEXAMPLEHERE
```

Puts the files in /home/public/GITEXAMPLE HERE, when I really want to put the files pulled not into its own subfolder, but into /home/public. I have looked around, and it seems to be an easy fix but I can not find anything on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clone directly to a directory ("." in your case).

See the following usage of "git clone" (or by typing typing "git clone" on your console):

```
git clone [options] [--] <repo> [<dir>]
```

So in your case that would be:

```
git clone GITEXAMPLEHERE .
```

After that you can use `git pull` and `git push` in the current folder.

Alternatively, you can move your files, including the ".git" directory to any other directory you want (if you cloned to the wrong folder).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
git clone <repo_url> /home/public/dir_name
```

Better still, do the clone in the folder where you want the repo to be created. You would replace the `dir_name` with a `.`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to fix your particular problem, you can just

```
cd /home/public/subdir
mv .git * ..
cd ..
rm -r subdir
```